# Deleting multiple items in a dict

Tags: python, dictionary, del

I've searched around for the error it gives me, but I don't understand that quite well. They did something with `for k, v in dbdata.items`, but that didn't work for me neither, it gives me other errors.

Well, I want is to delete multiple items.

```
tskinspath = ['1', '2']   

#
dbdata = {}
dbdata['test'] = {}
dbdata['test']['skins_t'] = {}

# Adds the items
dbdata['test']['skins_t']['1'] = 1
dbdata['test']['skins_t']['2'] = 0
dbdata['test']['skins_t']['3'] = 0
dbdata['test']['skins_t']['4'] = 0

# This doesn't work
for item in dbdata["test"]["skins_t"]:

     if item not in tskinspath:

        if dbdata["test"]["skins_t"][item] == 0:

                    del dbdata["test"]["skins_t"][item]

# exceptions.RunetimeError: dictonary changed size during iteration
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of iterating over the dictionary, iterate over `dict.items()`:

```
for key, value in dbdata["test"]["skins_t"].items():
     if key not in tskinspath:
        if value == 0:
            del dbdata["test"]["skins_t"][key]
```

On py3.x use `list(dbdata["test"]["skins_t"].items())`.

**Alternative:**

```
to_be_deleted = []
for key, value in dbdata["test"]["skins_t"].iteritems():
     if key not in tskinspath:
        if value == 0:
            to_be_deleted.append(key)
for k in to_be_deleted: 
    del dbdata["test"]["skins_t"][k]
```

Comment: So this is faster than the first answer, if there is a lot of data's or better? Just want to make sure I use the most accurate answer.

Comment: This works in Python2 (where `items()` returns a list), but not in Python3 (where `items()` returns a view of the underlying dictionary). I don't know what SO policy is on which version of Python should be assumed when the questioner doesn't say.

Comment: @Frederik `items()` will return a list a of key,value pairs  and `set(set(dbdata['test']['skins_t']))` would return a `set` of keys.So, in terms of memory set would be more efficient.

Comment: @Frederik I've added another solution, this one would take lesser memory.

Answer (score 0):

The error message says it: you shouldn't modify the dictionary that you are iterating over. Try

```
for item in set(dbdata['test']['skins_t']):
   ...
```

This way you are iterating over a set that contains all keys from `dbdata['test']['skins_t']`.

Comment: Why does it tell me that is it because of security reasons?


+ P.S
This is a question out of the box. I just want to make sure I use that correcly as well

There no different between `if item not in tskinspath:` `if not item in tskinspath:` 

What to use?

Comment: @Frederik `not in` is more human-readable and unambiguous in terms of precedence. It should be used.

Comment: @Frederik http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17659303/what-is-more-pythonic-for-not

Answer (score 0):

As the question details is way aside from the question, If you are looking for a solution that deletes multiple keys from a given `dict` use this snippet

```
[s.pop(k) for k in list(s.keys()) if k not in keep]
```

Additionally, you can create a new `dict` via comprehension.

```
new_dict = { k: old_dict[k] for k in keep }
```