# Python: "not" keyword placement

Tags: python

Which is more preferred below? and why?

Does PEP8 have a say in this?

```
if retcode != 0 and not "ignore_warning" in cmd_out:
```

or

```
if retcode != 0 and "ignore_warning" not in cmd_out:
```

functionally, i believe they achieve the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Use "is not" operator rather than "not ... is" . While both expressions are functionally identical, the former is more readable and preferred.

[PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations)

Comment: This has nothing to do with the `in` operator though.

Comment: Why it should be about `in`?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski because the original question is asking about `in`

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski I believe the point in this is about to make it more readable when using "not", regardless if it is used with "in" or "is". I found this answer as well, which explains more than I thought. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17659303/what-is-more-pythonic-for-not

Comment: The information you quoted is specifically about `is not` and not about the placement of `not` in general.

Comment: We can agree that PEP-8 is talking about `... is not ...`/`not ... is...`. But, is there anything about the *reason* given to prefer `is not` that doesn't apply to `not in` as well?

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the disassembled bytecode both the expressions are the same. From readability point of view second option is better.

```
if a != 10 and not b in "test":
```

and

```
if a != 10 and b not in "test":
```

gives the same disassembled code

```
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 (10)
              4 COMPARE_OP               3 (!=)
              6 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       26
              8 LOAD_FAST                1 (b)
             10 LOAD_CONST               2 ('test')
             12 COMPARE_OP               7 (not in)
             14 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       26
```